# How to create a temporary page to host an instance of a game with wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am using wordpress hosting for an online game website that I am creating for fun. I would like to create a temporary page (i.e. [www.game.com/temp-game](http://www.game.com/temp-game)) to host the game when a user starts a game, through the wordpress API. Then I can make temporary files associated with the game data to host the game, and display the game with a common template on the temporary page.

Does anyone have experience with doing this in wordpress? Or is there another solution that might be better to make this happen?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions